# How to make checkbox checked according to a value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I need to make checked status of my checkbox according to a data value. Up to now I am using below method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#update_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.update_data', function(){ 
           var row_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./project/userdetail.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{row_id:row_id},  
                dataType:"json", 
                success:function(data){  
                      ...........
                     if(data.accesslocations=='ABC,DEF,GHI'){
                      document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
                      document.getElementById("check2").checked = true;
                      document.getElementById("check3").checked = true;
                      
                     }

                     if(data.accesslocations=='ABC,GHI'){
                      document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
                      document.getElementById("check3").checked = true;
                      
                     }
                     if(data.accesslocations=='ABC'){
                      document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
                     }

                    
                     
                     
                     ...........

                 $('#employee_id_update').val(data.row_id);  
                 $('#insert').val("Update");
                 $('#new_data_Modal').modal('show'); 
                        
                      
                }, 
                error: function(req, status, error) {
               alert(req.responseText);      
                }   
           });  
      });
```

My intention is to check the `data.accesslocations` and check whether it contains `ABC` or `ABC,DEF` likewise,

```
If ABC contains need to check1 status as checked.
If DEF contains need to check2 status as checked.
If GHI contains need to check3 status as checked.
```

I have tried below method as well. But then I could not open my dialogbox, `new_data_Modal`.

```
               if(strstr(data.accesslocations, "ABC")){
                  document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
                 }
```

Comment: *"But then I could not open my dialogbox"* has some certain level of secrecy to it...

Comment: `data.accesslocations=='ABC,DEF,GHI'` I highly suspect that's your output, a silly string containing comma separate words... Is that really the case? Or you have an Array instead?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, you are correct. It is a string, not an array

Comment: Ah, OK if I got you right your modal opens just fine unless you use the last piece of code you've shown. So yeah... All I can think of is that you're missing to trigger a `.change()` event.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Array out of your string `"GHI,ABC"` → `["ABC", "GHI"]` using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- After you have you array, go for your elements values using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const handleFoobarCheckboxes = (str) => {
  const values = str.split(",");
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="foobar[]"]').forEach(elCkb => {
    elCkb.checked = values.includes(elCkb.value);
  });
};

handleFoobarCheckboxes("GHI,ABC");
```

```html
<label><input name="foobar[]" type="checkbox" value="ABC"> ABC</label>
<label><input name="foobar[]" type="checkbox" value="DEF"> DEF</label>
<label><input name="foobar[]" type="checkbox" value="GHI"> GHI</label>
```

as you can see from the example above, the order of values will not matter and your script will still work.

Comment: Thanks! How should I use this inside a if function?Can I use if(handleFoobarCheckboxes(ABC")) { my code } ?

Comment: No. That function already checkes and uncheckes the inputs as you can see in the demo.

Comment: Thank! got it. But I dont need to check after hardcoding the string. All I need to check the string data.accesslocations and check first checkbox if it contains ABC. need to check both first and two if contains ABC,DEF. Likewise. Hope you got that. If not I could elaborate more in question as well.

Comment: Well, I used a harrdcoded string for demo purpose obviously. Instead of my hardcoded string you would use `data.accesslocations` like: `handleFoobarCheckboxes(data.accesslocations)`- no difference. The script will work the same.